# Efficiently handling data in a web application

Tags: database, web-applications

I'm looking to find some material on how to efficiently handle model data in a web application. Currently, I use basic CRUD operations to access the database, do some business logic, and pass this data to the view where it can be manipulated by the user via a web interface. I'd like to learn more about optimizing data retrieval and data updating in web applications...any advice on where to read up on this?

Answer (score 0):

First it depends on your database. which Database and which Engine do you use ?

Then it depends one your data complexity ; Do you have a lot data that are linked to each other ? Do you uses a lot of index table ?

Then the data storage structure :
Do you want it faster in execution time or less cosumming memory ?

Because there is no bad technic, just 1 solution for 1 problem :)

Comment: I guess I am looking for a general answer, but it seems my question can go in many directions. I guess I am looking to optimize performance. I'm using MYSQL.

Answer (score 0):

What you should study is [DAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) design pattern.
For small sized databases it is the way to go. Read about it and then read examples in the language you are using.